# Multiple join conditions over a Many to Many relationship

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm writing an application that has three classes, Users, Posts and Groups.

A user may make a post, but can do so on behalf of themselves, and/or on behalf of one of their groups. Two or more users can also make a post in conjunction with each other, without a group. I'm trying to find a way to count the number of posts that a user is associated with, whether through themselves or one of their groups, and in the case where both assocations are present for only one post, it should only count as one.

User:

```
class User {
    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Post", inversedBy="users")
     */
    private $posts;

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group", inversedBy="users")
     */
    private $groups;
```

and the equivalent mappedBy on the other two entites.

I've written a MySQL query that seems to solve this

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT posts.id), users.name FROM users
LEFT JOIN post_user ON post_user.user_id = user.id
LEFT JOIN group_user ON group_user.user_id = user.id
LEFT JOIN post_group ON post_group.group_id = group_user.group_id
LEFT JOIN posts ON
    posts.id = post_user.post_id OR
    posts.id = post_group.post_id
GROUP BY users.id
```

which gives me a list of users, and the amount of posts they're associated with.

I'm having trouble finding a way to write this kind of query into the ORM language. The problem comes from the necessity to join to the ManyToMany join tables, as opposed to the entities' tables themselves. In the past, I've been able to write a condtional join using the 'WITH' statement.

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
    ->select('COUNT(DISTINCT p.id), u.name')
    ->leftJoin('u.groups', 'g')
    ->leftJoin('MyBundle:Post', 'p', 'WITH', 'p = u.posts OR p = g.posts')
```

This errors with

```
Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected.
```

and it's clear the problem stems from 'u.posts' and 'g.posts' referencing tables instead of fields.

I'm not really sure if Doctrine is capable of doing this kind of query, and I would prefer this be done on the database side, because there may be a large dataset to deal with, and this will need to be ordered by the count from the resultset.

Is there any way to reference the join table itself using DQL? and if not, is there a different kind of relational architecture that might solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion your primary concern should be the fact that you have many to many relationship in your database not the fact that the code does not work properly.

Create a view with a union of two queries. Gather the user id's from groups in one query and then gather the user id's from the independent users on the other query. Once you have the view you can do your counts.

Comment: Are you able to provide an example? I'm not sure how to do a union in DQL or the Doctrine Query Builder.